# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Border'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, colors, border

I have made a 5x5 grid in XAML where I put a TextBlock and a Border 5 times in each row. It looks like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOAbu.png)

I want to create an animation that goes through the row to show the user that it is checking the input. (Just to make it visible that the program is doing something, the actual checking happens differently).

The XAML code for the first row (I cut the rest off after the last border segment):

```
<Grid BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid Margin="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Width="350" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="450">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brush" Color="Silver"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="borderRow1Column1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" Height="50">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow1column1" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="borderRow1Column2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" Height="50">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow1column2" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="borderRow1Column3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" Height="50">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow1column3" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" ></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="borderRow1Column4" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" Height="50">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow1column4" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="borderRow1Column5" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brush}" BorderThickness="1" Width="50" Height="50">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbRow1column5" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <!-- More Rows following after this one -->

    </Grid>
```

Now I'd like to have a loop that goes through each textblock in that row, and instead of copy pasting it I want to reduce code by having a for loop with an index.

```
    private void displayCheckAnimation()
    {
        Color gray = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128, 128);
        Color black = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);

        Border borderRow1Column = new Border();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            borderRow1Column[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(gray);
            Task.Delay(50).Wait();
            borderRow1Column[i].Background = new SolidColorBrush(black);
            Task.Delay(50).Wait();
        }
    }
```

But this gives me the error

```
CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'Border'
```

Any solutions as to how I can loop through my row?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this exception is because you declared a Border and are trying to index it as an array of Borders. You should use the actual border instances instead.

Without changing your XAML, I can see a few ways of doing this. You could use reflection to get your specific borders, or create a list of all your borders first and just loop through the list.

Using reflection, you could get the instance using a string of the name. Since the name of the borders can easily be constructed using your row and column numbers, this is an easy solution. However, although in some cases reflection can be a good idea to use, it often is not.

Another solution is to first create a list with your borders and loop through it. Something like this:

```
List<Border> borders = new List<Border>()
{
    borderRow1Column1,
    borderRow1Column2,
    etc.
}

foreach (var border in borders)
{
    border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(gray);
    Task.Delay(50).Wait();
    border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(black);
    Task.Delay(50).Wait();
}
```

I would like to advise you to check out the animations in WPF. These are actually meant for animations. You can make it look really nice that way. The animation that changes color is [ColorAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation(v=vs.110).aspx).